# xsendfile on Amazon EC2 AMI

Tags: apache, apache2, amazon-ec2, apache-modules

I'm trying to install `xsendfile` on Amazon's own Linux AMI with this command:

```
yum install mod_xsendfile
```

but it can't find the package. Can anyone help with a solution please?

Comment: Which Linux distribution (CentOS, Fedora, Ubuntu etc.) does your AMI use ?  You probably need to enable an additional package repository, but the location ofthe repo depends on your distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, but you might have to download some packages to be able to compile it

> wget https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/mod_xsendfile.c --no-check-certificate

and for apache2 to compile it's:

> apxs2 -cia mod_xsendfile.c